# Error callback not called on 400 HTTP Return

Tags: backbone.js

I have a RESTful service that, when I try to save a new record does a unique email check. When it fails, I return a 400 error code along with a JSON message with an "errors" value in it.

Unfortunately, my error callback on my save doesn't seem to be firing. Any suggestions?

```
var nRecord = new RecordModel(values);
nRecord.save({
    wait: true,
    error: function(model,response){
        console.log('error2');
        obj.errorHandler(model,response);
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log('success2');
        obj.alert('Information saved!','Record Created!','success');

        // if there were no errors, clear the list
        $('#record-form :input').val('');
    }
});
```

"Error2" is never displayed in the console. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be passing your error handler and other options as model attributes and saved into the model instead. Trying passing null as a first parameter to the save function.  Hopefully this will make it work :)

```
nRecord.save(null,{
    wait: true,
    error: function(model,response){
        console.log('error2');
        obj.errorHandler(model,response);
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log('success2');
        obj.alert('Information saved!','Record Created!','success');

        // if there were no errors, clear the list
        $('#record-form :input').val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm... I have the same problem, but with `fetch()`, not `save()`. This solution does not work for me (backbone 0.9.2). I tried with `(originalModel, resp, options)` arguments, as found in the source code for the onError callback. I don't understand...

Comment: This solution does not work for me either. What is the accepted method?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and the problem was i was overwriting the sync in the model. This meant the options was not getting passed in.

```
completeCustomer.save(null, {
                wait: true,
                error: function(model,response){
                    console.log('error2');
                    //obj.errorHandler(model,response);
                    _.bind(this.handleError, this);
                },
                success: function() {
                    console.log('success2');
                    //_.bind(this.handleSuccess, this);
                }
            });
```